# Servlet isn't working

Tags: java, servlets

I've got a HelloWorld servlet (read, "I'm a java noob") and its not working in tomcat7.  Can someone help me understand why its not working?  Note, I'm using the out-of-the-box configurations for tomcat7.  I've also confirmed that the `ROOT` default webapp works fine confirming that tomcat can startup, java is configured properly, etc.

```
// Import required java libraries
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

// Extend HttpServlet class
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {

  private String message;

  public void init() throws ServletException
  {
      // Do required initialization
      message = "Hello World";
  }

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
  {
      // Set response content type
      response.setContentType("text/html");

      // Actual logic goes here.
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");
  }

  public void destroy()
  {
      // do nothing.
  }
}
```

*note:  I got this source online from a Hello World tutorial*

So, I compiled it like so:

`javac -cp /usr/local/tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar ./HelloWorld.java`

And then I moved the compiled `HelloWorld.class` to `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/hello/WEB-INF/classes`.  I then created the following `web.xml` file:

```
<web-app
  version="2.4"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
  xsi:schemalocation="http:/java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

[Edit 1:  Adding curl command with response]

```
[vagrant@scep webapps]$ curl localhost:8080/hello -v


* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... connected
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /hello HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.13.6.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Location: http://localhost:8080/hello/
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Mon, 24 Feb 2014 04:31:07 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

And here's the test with `/`:

```
[vagrant@scep webapps]$ curl localhost:8080/hello/ -v
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... connected
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /hello/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.13.6.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Language: en
< Content-Length: 963
< Date: Mon, 24 Feb 2014 04:32:07 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 - Error report</title><!-- a lot of stuff, truncated --></html>
```

[Edit 1:  Added `tree` of the `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps` directory]

```
[vagrant@scep webapps]$ tree
.
└── hello
    └── WEB-INF
        ├── classes
        │   └── HelloWorld.class
        └── web.xml
```

Comment: Just checking the obvious here, did you restart tomcat after you copied the class file? Also check using netstat the pid bound into 8080 is actually your tomcat's process (not other process) (happened to me before)

Comment: Yes.  I had been restarted it on each update, but then I noticed that out-of-the-box it is configured to reload when `web.xml` is changed.  That was confirmed when I saved a meaningless update and the log showed up again.

Comment: I *think* you just need to flush the print writer as its not set to autoflush. `out.flush()` after you print. The 302 indicates the servlet was found. The docs also mention this: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter()

Comment: Where did you put the `web.xml`?

Comment: @BrianRoach I don't think you need to flush. I tested OP's exact code and it prints Hello World ok for me. I think OP has other problem (eg web.xml placement, tomcat setup/config etc)

Comment: @gerrytan -- Well, cool.  :)  I'll keep fiddling with it.  Maybe someday it will actually do what I mean for it to do.

Comment: Few more suggestions: check your catalina.log, make sure there's no exception there, check your localhost_access.log, make sure the request did get registered in there. Check your /etc/hosts file (god forbid localhost actually isn't 127.0.0.1 for you)

Answer (score 1):

As your servlet is in the `hello` webApp you need to call localhost:8080/hello/hello

The URL pattern of / has a special meaning. It namely indicates the "Default Servlet" URL pattern. So every request which does not match any of the other more specific URL patterns in web.xml will ultimately end up in this servlet.

Having a look at section 4.3.3 of roguewave.com/portals/0/products/hydraexpress/docs/3.5.0/html/… indicates that the default servlet will only be used if all other matches fail. So in reality, my URL should and so should yours.

Rather than curl, try using a browser.

Comment: I don't think this is correct answer, the servlet hello is mapped into / (see web.xml)

Comment: @scotth Your case would be correct if the mapping is `<url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>`, but the code posted by OP is `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`. This is the servlet's mapping, not the context path. Tomcat implies the context path is `/hello` because the app is deployed in folder called `hello`. So the correct url is http://localhost:8080/hello/

Comment: I still think your answer is out of context. OP has clearly indicated the app is placed on `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/hello`, hence Tomcat will imply the context path /hello. The URL he tested is also http://localhost:8080/hello. Other default settings are unlikely to be altered since he mentioned the tomcat install is out-of-the-box

Comment: @gerrytan I have finally figured out that you are not saying something I thought you were.  Anyway, having a look at section 4.3.3 of http://www.roguewave.com/portals/0/products/hydraexpress/docs/3.5.0/html/rwsfservletug/4-3.html indicates that the default servlet will only be used if all other matches fail.  So in reality, my URL should and so should yours.

Answer (score 0):

I know your doing right one method. but, you just try this method. At the same time your doing condition will following type as:

1. A string beginning with a '/' character and ending with a '/*' suffix is used for path mapping.
2. A string beginning with a '*.' prefix is used as an extension mapping.
3. A string containing only the '/' character indicates the "default" servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.
4. All other strings are used for exact matches only.

you just try this method.

```
<servlet-class>package.name of the servlet controller</servlet-class>
```